# Merge elements having common tag in xml file

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I have created a xml file using ElementTree in Python. I am very new to python so please forgive if am making some mistakes in terms.
I want to merge the contents of elements having the same attribute name.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<DefaultLines>
    <Files Date="2020-10-23" Name="D:\report_byfile_detailed.txt">
        <FileName file="emem_fifo_1c.vhd  ">
            <DefLines>
                <Message>'120'<Child>Statement</Child>w_addr &lt;= (others =&gt; '0');</Message>
            </DefLines>
            <DefLines>
                <Message>'136'<Child>Statement</Child>r_addr &lt;= (others =&gt; '0');</Message>
            </DefLines>
        </FileName>
        <FileName file="emem_fifo_1c.vhd  ">
            <DefLines>
                <Message>'119'<Child>Branch</Child>if (SRESET = '1') then</Message>
            </DefLines>
        </FileName>
    </Files>
</DefaultLines>
```

For e.g Filename1 and Filename2 have the same attribute i.e "emem_fifo_1c.vhd  ". I want the elements inside the FileName to be merged into one if "file" is the same.

My output xml should look like

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<DefaultLines>
    <Files Date="2020-10-23" Name="D:\report_byfile_detailed.txt">
        <FileName file="emem_fifo_1c.vhd  ">
            <DefLines>
                <Message>'120'<Child>Statement</Child>w_addr &lt;= (others =&gt; '0');</Message>
            </DefLines>
            <DefLines>
                <Message>'136'<Child>Statement</Child>r_addr &lt;= (others =&gt; '0');</Message>
            </DefLines>
            <DefLines>
                <Message>'119'<Child>Branch</Child>if (SRESET = '1') then</Message>
            </DefLines>
        </FileName>
    </Files>
</DefaultLines>
```

I am really clueless how to do the same using ElementTree in python.

Update:
I was about to solve this issue with the help of dabingsou. However I am facing another issue of duplicate content inside the nodes. I am trying to remove them while adding them into the xml but it is not working.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<DefaultLines>
    <Files Date="2020-10-31" Name="D:\report_byfile_detailed.txt">
        <FileName file="emem_fifo_1c.vhd ">
            <DefLines>
                <Message>'108'<Child>Expression</Child>Item    1  ((W_EN and not(fifo_full)) and not(SRESET))</Message>
                <Justification />
                <Comment />
                <Status />
            </DefLines>
            <DefLines>
                <Message>'119'<Child>Branch</Child>if (SRESET = '1') then</Message>
                <Justification />
                <Comment />
                <Status />
            </DefLines>
            <DefLines>
                <Message>108<Child>Expression</Child>Item    1  ((W_EN and not(fifo_full)) and not(SRESET))</Message>
                <Justification />
                <Comment />
                <Status />
            </DefLines>
            <DefLines>
                <Message>109<Child>Expression</Child>Item    1  ((R_EN and not(fifo_empty)) and not(SRESET))</Message>
                <Justification />
                <Comment />
                <Status />
            </DefLines>
            <DefLines>
            <DefLines>
                <Message>108<Child>Expression</Child>Item    1  ((W_EN and not(fifo_full)) and not(SRESET))</Message>
                <Justification />
                <Comment />
                <Status />
            </DefLines>
            <DefLines>
                <Message>Row   4:<Child>Expression</Child>fifo_full_1 not SRESET &amp;&amp; W_EN</Message>
                <Justification />
                <Comment />
                <Status />
            </DefLines>
            <DefLines>
                <Message>Row   6:<Child>Expression</Child>SRESET_1 (W_EN and not(fifo_full))</Message>
                <Justification />
                <Comment />
                <Status />
            </DefLines>
            <DefLines>
                <Message>Row   4:<Child>Expression</Child>fifo_full_1           not SRESET &amp;&amp; W_EN</Message>
                <Justification />
                <Comment />
                <Status />
            </DefLines>
            <DefLines>
                <Message>Row   6:<Child>Expression</Child>SRESET_1              (W_EN and not(fifo_full))</Message>
                <Justification />
                <Comment />
                <Status />
            </DefLines>
```

'108', '109' 'Row4', Row6' is getting appended multiple times. Is it possible i keep only the first occurrence and remove the rest.

Update:
After using the method to remove duplicates,I am getting xml having incomplete nodes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<DefaultLines>
<Files Date="2020-11-01" Name="D:\report_byfile_detailed.txt">
<FileName file="emem_fifo_1c.vhd ">
<DefLines>
<Message>
'108'
<Child>Expression</Child>
Item    1  ((W_EN and not(fifo_full)) and not(SRESET))
</Message>
<Justification />
<Comment />
<Status />
</DefLines>
<DefLines>
<Message>
'119'
<Child>Branch</Child>
if (SRESET = '1') then
</Message>
<Justification />
<Comment />
<Status />
</DefLines>
<DefLines>
<Message>
'120'
<Child>Statement</Child>
w_addr &lt;= (others =&gt; '0');
</Message>
<Justification />
<Comment />
<Status />
</DefLines>
<DefLines>
<Message>
'135'
<Child>Branch</Child>
if (SRESET = '1') then
</Message>
<Justification />
<Comment />
<Status />
</DefLines>

<DefLines>
<Message>
'136'
<Child>Statement</Child>
r_addr &lt;= (others =&gt; '0');
</Message>
<Justification />
<Comment />
<Status />
</DefLines>
<DefLines>
<Message>
'157'
<Child>Branch</Child>
if (SRESET = '1') then
</Message>
<Justification />
<Comment />
<Status />
</DefLines>
<DefLines>
<Message>
'158'
<Child>Statement</Child>
fifo_empty &lt;= '1';
</Message>
<Justification />
<Comment />
<Status />
</DefLines>
<DefLines>
<Message>
'180'
<Child>Branch</Child>
if (SRESET = '1') then
</Message>
<Justification />
<Comment />
<Status />
</DefLines>

<DefLines>
<Message>
'181', '182'
<Child>Statement</Child>
fifo_used     &lt;= (others =&gt; '0');
fifo_used_one &lt;= '0';
</Message>
<Justification />
<Comment />
<Status />
</DefLines>
Message>
<Justification />
<Comment />
<Status />
</DefLines>
<DefLines>
<Message>
'568', '569', '570', '571'
<Child>Statement</Child>
config_rd_fsm                     

    &lt;= '0';
axi4_lite_slave_rdata_ch_out &lt;= AXI4LITE_RDATA32_S2M_DEF;
config_rd_fsm                &lt;= IDLE;
</Message>
<Justification />
<Comment />
<Status />
**<

<DefLines>**
<Message>
161
<Child>Condition</Child>
Item    1  (((r_en_valid = '1') and (fifo_used_one = '1')) and (w_en_valid = '0'))
</Message>
<Justification />
<Comment />
<Status />
</DefLines>
DefLines>

<DefLines>
<Message>
367
<Child>Branch</Child>
when others =&gt;
</Message>
<Justification />
<Comment />
<Status />
</DefLines>
<DefLines>
<Message>
**<Child>Bran**

<DefLines>
<Message>
Row   5:    
<Child>Condition</Child>
(w_en_valid = '0')_0     ((r_en_valid = '1') and (fifo_used_one = '1'))
</Message>
<Justification />
<Comment />
<Status />
**</DefLines>sh</Child>**
All False Count
</Message>
<Justification />
<Comment />
<Status />
</DefLines>
<DefLines>
<Message>
587
<Child>Branch</Child>
when others =&gt;
</Message>
**<Justi>**


</FileName>
```

I have tried to bold the areas where the tree is coming incomplete and hence i am getting error while generating and parsing the xml tree

Comment: Can you use the lxml library instead? It's much easier that way.

Comment: my entire code is based on element tree. It will be really helpful if you could give some idea how lxml can be used in this situation. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

This is how it can be done with lxml; I'll try to explain as we go along.

The basic principle is that we choose, randomly, the first `FileName` as the repository of the target information, paste that target information into it, and then delete the parent of that target.

```
    from lxml import etree
    deflines = """<?xml version="1.0" ?>
    <DefaultLines>
        <Files Date="2020-10-23" Name="D:\report_byfile_detailed.txt">
            <FileName file="emem_fifo_1c.vhd  ">
                <DefLines>
                    <Message>'120'<Child>Statement</Child>w_addr &lt;= (others =&gt; '0');</Message>
                </DefLines>
                <DefLines>
                    <Message>'136'<Child>Statement</Child>r_addr &lt;= (others =&gt; '0');</Message>
                </DefLines>
            </FileName>
          <FileName file="some_other_name.text">
                <DefLines>
                    <Message>'xxxx'<Child>Branch</Child>if (yyyyy= '1000') then</Message>
                </DefLines>
            </FileName>
            <FileName file="emem_fifo_1c.vhd  " id="mushi">
                <DefLines>
                    <Message>'119'<Child>Branch</Child>if (SRESET = '1') then</Message>
                </DefLines>
            </FileName>       
        </Files>
    </DefaultLines>
    """
    # I added another FileName which doesn't meet the requirements, just to demonstrate how it works
    
    doc = etree.XML(deflines)
    destination = doc.xpath('//Files/FileName[1]//DefLines')[0]
    for  dl in doc.xpath('//FileName[@file="emem_fifo_1c.vhd  "][position()>1]//DefLines'): #position has to be >1 to make sure we skip the destination element        
        dl.getparent().getparent().remove(dl.getparent()) #the target was inside a parent which to be removed; so we search for the target's grandparent 
        destination.append(dl)
    print(etree.tostring(doc, xml_declaration = True).decode())
```

Comment: Hi jack, Thanks for the explanation and the code. Just wanted to ask that in the line "for  dl in doc.xpath('//FileName[@file="emem_fifo_1c.vhd  "][position()>1]//DefLines'): ", are you hardcoding the file artifact?  Because there maybe different filenames also which maybe similar and I may have to merge their contents just like "emem_fifo_1c.vhd"

Comment: @SupratikBiswas Yes, the filename is hardcoded, because it's the only one you had as a target in your sample xml. You obviously can change the name in the code -if you only have one target per xml. If you have more than one target in the same xml file, you'll have to create a list of these names, wrap the whole code in a `for` loop and iterate through the names on the list

Comment: Yes I have more than one target in the same xml file. I will have to apply the same condition i.e merge the content of file having same name to all this target files. I am not sure of creating a list of filenames as again duplicate may arise

Comment: @SupratikBiswas That's a different question and you should actually post it as a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

Another method, for your reference.

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc, utils
xml = '''
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<DefaultLines>
   <Files Date="2020-10-23" Name="D:\report_byfile_detailed.txt">
      <FileName file="emem_fifo_1c.vhd  ">
            <DefLines>
               <Message>'120'<Child>Statement</Child>w_addr &lt;= (others =&gt; '0');</Message>
            </DefLines>
            <DefLines>
               <Message>'136'<Child>Statement</Child>r_addr &lt;= (others =&gt; '0');</Message>
            </DefLines>
      </FileName>
      <FileName file="some_other_name.text">
            <DefLines>
               <Message>'xxxx'<Child>Branch</Child>if (yyyyy= '1000') then</Message>
            </DefLines>
      </FileName>
      <FileName file="emem_fifo_1c.vhd  " id="mushi">
            <DefLines>
               <Message>'119'<Child>Branch</Child>if (SRESET = '1') then</Message>
            </DefLines>
      </FileName>       
   </Files>
</DefaultLines>
'''

dic = {}
doc = SimplifiedDoc(xml)
nodes = doc.selects('Files>FileName')
for node in nodes:
   last = dic.get(node['file'])
   if last:
      last.appendChild(node.html)
      node.remove()
   else:
      dic[node['file']]=node
      
# print (doc.html)
# remove the duplicate items
nodes = doc.selects('Files>FileName')
for node in nodes:
    dic.clear()
    lst = node.selects('DefLines')
    if len(lst) <= 1:
        continue
    for n in lst:
        key = n.select('Message').firstText()
        exist = dic.get(key)
        if exist:
            n.remove()
        else:
            dic[key] = True
# Sort
nodes = doc.selects('Files>FileName')
for node in nodes:
    dic.clear()
    lst = node.selects('DefLines')
    if len(lst) <= 1:
        continue
    for n in lst:
        dic[n.select('Message').firstText()] = n.outerHtml # Cache, replace it below.

    i = 0
    for key in sorted(dic):
        lst[i].replaceSelf(dic[key]) # Replace after sorting
        i = i + 1
# Save
utils.saveFile('test.xml', doc.html)
```

Result：

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<DefaultLines>
   <Files Date="2020-10-23" Name="D: eport_byfile_detailed.txt">
      <FileName file="emem_fifo_1c.vhd ">
            <DefLines>
               <Message>'119'<Child>Branch</Child>if (SRESET = '1') then</Message>
            </DefLines>
            <DefLines>
               <Message>'120'<Child>Statement</Child>w_addr &lt;= (others =&gt; '0');</Message>
            </DefLines>
      
            <DefLines>
               <Message>'136'<Child>Statement</Child>r_addr &lt;= (others =&gt; '0');</Message>
            </DefLines>
      </FileName>
      <FileName file="some_other_name.text">
            <DefLines>
               <Message>'xxxx'<Child>Branch</Child>if (yyyyy= '1000') then</Message>
            </DefLines>
      </FileName>       
   </Files>
</DefaultLines>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223938/discussion-on-answer-by-dabingsou-merge-elements-having-common-tag-in-xml-file).